# pass by reference in c++/c

Tags: c++, c, pass-by-reference

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sq(int &b) {
    b=b+12;
}

void main() {

int a=5;
sq(a);
printf("%d",a);

}
```

In the above c program, it does not work but the same works in c++ i.e.

```
#include<iostream>

void sq(int &b) {
    b=b+12;
}

 int main() {

int a=5;
sq(a);
std::cout<<a;

}
```

Is there a difference in how the variable is passed in c++ ?? whydoes it work in c++ ? 
is above code pass by reference in c++ ?

Comment: Unlike C++, C doesn't have references, only pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?  Do you mean you don't see 17 printed out, or that it doesn't compile?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does the code compile in C++, but not in C? Or does it compile and not output what you expect?

Comment: Not sure why you are surprised that code written for one language does not compile as the other. You can't run javascript in a perl interpreter, why should you be able to run C++ code in a C compiler.

Comment: @loki i was not running either one using a wrong compiler ...was just trying to compare ! 
i have been using c and trying to learn ... but in c++ the parameter is not passed the same way i.e. in calling function its not passed with an & in the front... and in the called function a '*' is not being used to get that address .... Thus my big question was how is it happenig in c++ ?

Comment: The point is two different languages; C is not C++. They don't share much apart from a superficial syntax similarity (which all languages derived from C do).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C and C++ are different languages. C does not have references.

If you want reference semantics in C, then use pointers:

```
void sq(int * b) {      // Pass by pointer
    *b = *b + 12;       // Dereference the pointer to get the value
}

int main() {            // Both languages require a return type of int
    int a = 5;
    sq(&a);             // Pass a pointer to a
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;           // C used to require this, while C++ doesn't
                        //     if you're compiling as C99, you can leave it out
}
```

Comment: C hasn't needed `return 0;` since C99.

Comment: @LucDanton: Fair enough, I haven't really used C since 1999.

Comment: two ways of passing parameters in c is 1) pass by value, 2) pass by reference (pointers) right ?

Comment: @hunterr986: Yes (although a pedant might say that both are passing by value, and one of the values happens to be a pointer). C++ adds reference types, so you can genuinely pass by reference.

Comment: @hunterr986: C has one way of passing parameters[\*]: by value. When you pass *by-pointer* you are actually passing a pointer by value. [\*] Actually there are corner cases in arrays and functions, that are never passed by *value*, and rather *decay* into a pointer (that is itself passed by value)

Comment: @LucDanton: Most C compilers (that also double as C++ compilers) did not default to C99 though. gcc defaulted to C89 and MS compilers cl1 did not even support C99. I have not checked but things have probably changed since the release of C++11.